# Accessibility for UITextField with custom inputView (VoiceOver)

Tags: ios, accessibility, uipickerview, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I have an `UITextField` that uses a `UIPickerView` with two columns as `inputView`.

[image: When the user taps on the Target Range cell, the picker at the bottom appears]

*Image: When the user taps on the Target Range cell, the picker at the bottom appears.*

I'm wondering how to optimise the VoiceOver experience for this setup.

1. When tapping the text field VoiceOver says "[...] Insertion Point at end" This is misleading to the user, because he doesn't need to care about the caret. How can I fix that?
2. I'm not sure: Should the focus change to the picker view automatically after the double tapping the text field?
3. How to communicate to the user that there are two components in the `UIPickerView` and that the left one represents the lower target range and the right one represents the upper target range?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use the STATIC TEXT TRAIT on the input field.

2) Yes

3) I'd separate the two values. Have a picker for each, instead of this advanced picker with both.

If this isn't possible, you'll want to add that information in. That information might make a good accessibilityHint. It's something that users that frequent your app will become accustomed to, so it's not crucial information. But, new users might need reminded.

Note: users can turn off hints, so if you feel that information is critical, it would be better to bundle it in with the accessibilityLabel.

Answer (score 0):

For point number 1, just assign "nil" value to textfieldName.text

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).